# How to create a paint stroke that can flow along a path

Tags: animation

I am still fairly new to blender and regarding this matter, only have a rough understanding of getting a liquid to follow a curve.

I am looking to create a paint stroke that can follow and extend along a curve (I have attached a link to a reference point below). I would like for the paint to have a taper off the end (if achievable) to give that paint stroke look and also have some of the stroke texture.

Sorry if this is not overly clear. Basically as shown in the video linked below.

[Paint stroke reference video](https://youtu.be/smvyxABRZTU)

Comment: Model your paint object and make it follow a curve with a Curve modifier?

Comment: @moonboots would this method be able to flow and leave a trail behind it like in the video? Sorry I have not done much in this area before.

Comment: do you have a better quality video?

Comment: @moonboots https://youtu.be/smvyxABRZTU

Comment: I'm not sure the tail even changes its shape, so you could simply make a long flat shape follow a curve with the help of the Curve modifier. You can change its shape if needed with shapekeys or Displace modifier, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a plane subdivide it, sculpt some horizontal grooves, stretch it:

[image]

Create a curve, give your painting object a *Curve* modifier with the curve as target, give it also a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

In the curve Shape, choose *Twist Method > Z-Up*. Move the object along the correct axis, it will follow the curve:

[image]

Comment: that looks like it will work perfectly! Thank you so much for all your help with this. It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome, if you meet a problem somewhere in the process don't hesitate to ask

Comment: thank you so much! I hope I can make this work now!